# Does with-statement function close files?

Tags: python, with-statement

In this simple file IO operation, is `x.txt` closed at the end of `f.read`?
Also, how would I check to see if that file is still open or not?

```
with open("x.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
```

Comment: Yes opening using `with` will close the file.

Comment: it closes once the block ends, not after a `read`, you can read the file again if you run `f.seek(0)`.

Answer (score 4):

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

> It is good practice to use the with keyword when dealing with file
>   objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after
>   its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way. It is
>   also much shorter than writing equivalent try-finally blocks:

Comment: In fact, this began so be so since 2.6. In 2.5 (where `with` was introduced), built-in objects didn't yet support the context manager interface.

Answer (score 3):

The file object referenced by `f` will be closed when control leaves the with-statement's code block.  In fact, that is why you use a with-statement to open a file in the first place.  Other than automatically closing the file when done, the construct serves no purpose.

You can test this for yourself by printing the [`f.closed` flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.closed):

```
with open("x.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
    ## Still inside with block ##
    print f.closed  # Output: False

## Outside of with block ##
print f.closed  # Output: True
```

Comment: I just started Python on Tuesday. I appreciate the help.

Comment: It might be worth adding another `print f.closed` inside the `with` statement, to show exactly where it happens (in particular, the distinction Rafael Barros made in a comment).